# Fit exponential curve to data points to calculate decay rate

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy, curve-fitting, data-fitting

I have a set of data points that looks like this:

```
x = [0, 2, 4, 7] 
y = [100, 62, 60, 56]
```

and I need to fit an exponential curve that follows the following equation:

```
C = C0 * e^(-kdecay*t)
```

where C is y, C0 is the value of y at the time point 0, and t is x.

At the moment I have the code to plot the time points, but I need to add the exponential curve.

```
plt.plot(x,y,color='indianred', ls='none', linewidth=2)
plt.errorbar(x,y,yerr,marker='o', color='indianred', ls='none', ecolor='k')

#set y axis limits
plt.ylim((0,120))

plt.xlabel("ActD (h)", fontsize=14)
plt.ylabel("mRNA (%)", fontsize=14)
```

Many thanks in advance for your help.

EDIT:
I was trying this

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

def func(C, kdecay, x):
    y= C*np.exp(-kdecay*x)
    return y
popt, _ = curve_fit(func, x, y)
C, kdecay = pop
```

I probably miss this part, since it's not in the same shape as my function:

```
print('y=%.5f*x+%.5f'%(C,kdecay))
```

I'm really new with Python, if you could give me a clear answer instead of just suggesting a library it would be really helpful.

Comment: This might help you: http://home.ustc.edu.cn/~lipai/auto_examples/plot_exp.html

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't look like it gives back a function. A part from plotting the curve, I also need the values of the function.

Comment: You can loop over the x values with your function and get the y values right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're familiar with least squares, you can convert your equation to a valid form for LS by taking a logarithm:

```
y(t) = a * e^(-b*t)
```

becomes

```
ln(y(t)) = ln(a) - b*t
```

In terms of logarithms, this is a simple linear equation for `t`.

Luckily, `scipy` can do that for you:

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import numpy as np

def your_function(t, a, b):
    return a * np.exp(-b*t)

x = [0, 2, 4, 7] 
y = [100, 62, 60, 56]

best_params = curve_fit(your_function, x, y)
print(best_params)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not familiar with it. What I'm missing is, once I have the function, how can I apply it to my data? I know that you can do it with curve_fit from scipy but the functions they use are always different and I can't make it work on my data

Comment: Try the code I just posted @CarmenGrandi.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I get this: (array([96.18651421,  0.12779204]), array([[5.21250709e+01, 1.44493710e-01],
       [1.44493710e-01, 8.33950032e-04]]))

How can I get the function?

Comment: I managed to get the function, but the values are completely different from what I get on excel:
`Python -> y=93.20158*e^(-0.09921*x)`
`Excel -> y = 111.55*e^(-0.1997*x)`

Comment: @CarmenGrandi I'd recommend plotting both curves and observing which fits your data best. I know not how excel handles curve fitting.

Comment: Plotting both myself in GeoGebra, I clearly see that Excel does not use least squares, because the difference between `111.55 * e^(-0.1997 * 7)` and `56` is massive. It might be using least squares, but not optimizing for this difference, but for difference in x values or even distance of points from the curve. You need to figure out which of these approaches works best for you.